# Does TBB reveal its file directory address to websites?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle

I got this error once when I tried to open particular site :

> XML Parsing Error: unexpected parser state
>   Location: jar:file:*///home/USERNAME/tor-browser_en-US/*tor-browser_en-US%203.5.4/Browser/omni.ja!/chrome/toolkit/content/global/netError.xhtml
>   Line Number 304, Column 68:

Is the directory address /home/*USERNAME*/ is revealed to a website or not, when www browsing with Tor Browser Bundle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This bug is [#569229](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=569229) in Mozilla's bugtracker. The Tor Project has [trac entry #8842](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/ticket/8842) which deals with the problem. Both only discuss the bug and don't provide a solution yet. From what I see and interpret this message is only sent to you and informs you about a local problem. Some comments in the Mozilla bugtracker suggest that the errors occurs when there are DNS problems or when the PC goes to sleep mode.

So it is a local problem and the website doesn't see this particular error message.

Comment: Ok, that was scary to wonder if sites would be able to see Username in directory address. Thanks. I will mark it answer.